# How to show text/info in certain place on textover using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

http://www.baelkopat.com/GECCo/goingGreenTest.html is what I have so far. What I need to learn is how to show the additional text when a user `mouseOver`s the link. i.e. when a user `mouseOver`s on "Activity Guide(PDF)" the "Download and print...." shows up.
I have pretty good experience with ActionScript not that very new to JavaScript. I was wondering how to make the `mouseOver` effect happen.

The hover div is crated using css

## overTextA{

```
position:absolute;
left:190px;
top:7px;
width:280px;
padding:10px 15px;
background-image:url(../images/navMenuOver.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
z-index:3;
```

}

## overTextB{

```
position:absolute;
left:190px;
top:40px;
width:280px;
padding:10px 15px;
background-image:url(../images/navMenuOver.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
z-index:3;
```

}

and in HTML

```
<div id="overTextA"> Download and print a PDF-version of the Junior <i>Going Green with GECCo</i> guide, with activity information, instructions, and resources. </div>

<div id="overTextB"> Take the <i>GECCo Challenge !</i> Help our planet by saving energy AND earning money for conservation.</div>
```

I am not sure that is the best way to do it but for now I just want to have a workable version working that shows the appropriate text when `mouseOver` on the nav link.

Thanks, Rex

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this in a straight forward fashion using a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).
Here is a tutorial that will walk you through using a `.hover()` function:

http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/02/quick-tip-set-hover-class-for-anything

**Clarification:**

Add / remove your classes to the hover element, adding would display it, and removing or hiding it would take the text element away.  jQuery is very useful when you don't want to dive into JS too much. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply... I looked into the site but didn't quite get it...
Even though I don't know much about javascript I want to stick with it and get the basics first before start using other libraries...
Thanks,Rex

Comment: rex, using a library is not difficult, you create a java script include in the header, and just use the function. Honestly easier than you think.